# FTP downloads via PowerShell PSFTP module crashes with folders. (550 error)

Tags: powershell, ftp

I want to download some folders and files from another server via FTP using PowerShell [PSFTP module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSFTP/).
I want to download all files and folders from the specified address.

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41498044/14163843) answer I wrote the next script:

```
$User = "xxxxx"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "xxxx" -AsPlainText -Force
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($User, $Password)

$ftp_server = "ftp://backup.xxxxx.eu"
$ftp_path = "backup_old/xxx/xx_Config_Backup"
$local_path = "D:\Backup\backup_old\xxx"

Set-FTPConnection -Credentials $Credentials -Server $ftp_server -EnableSsl -ignoreCert -UsePassive
Get-FTPChildItem -path $ftp_path -Recurse | Get-FTPItem -localpath $local_path -Overwrite -Verbose #-RecreateFolders
```

This script works fine when `ftp_path`'s folder consists of just files.

```
ContentLength           : -1
Headers                 : {}
SupportsHeaders         : True
ResponseUri             : ftp://backup.xxxxx.eu/
StatusCode              : ClosingData
StatusDescription       : 226 Transfer complete.
                          
LastModified            : 01.01.0001 0:00:00
BannerMessage           : 220 Microsoft FTP Service
                          
WelcomeMessage          : 230 User logged in.
                          
ExitMessage             : 221 Goodbye.
                          
IsFromCache             : False
IsMutuallyAuthenticated : False
ContentType             : 

VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Download item: 'ftp://backup.xxxxx.eu
/backup_old/xxx/QlikView/xxx.qvw'" on target "".
226 Transfer complete.

VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Download item: 'ftp://backup.xxxxx.eu
/backup_old/xxx/QlikView/xxxFulFillment.qvw'" on target "D:\Backup\backu
p_old\xxx\xxx.qvw".
226 Transfer complete.
```

But when it consists of additional folders with files, it creates a file with zero-size named same as folder and crashes with 550 error.

```
ContentLength           : -1
Headers                 : {}
SupportsHeaders         : True
ResponseUri             : ftp://backup.xxxxx.eu/
StatusCode              : ClosingData
StatusDescription       : 226 Transfer complete.
                          
LastModified            : 01.01.0001 0:00:00
BannerMessage           : 220 Microsoft FTP Service
                          
WelcomeMessage          : 230 User logged in.
                          
ExitMessage             : 221 Goodbye.
                          
IsFromCache             : False
IsMutuallyAuthenticated : False
ContentType             : 

VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Download item: 'ftp://backup.xxxxx.eu
/backup_old/xxx/xx_Config_Backup/AlertSender'" on target "".
Get-FTPItem : Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote
 server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no acc
ess)."
At C:\PS_Scrips\PSFTP_1.ps1:13 char:45
+ ...  -Recurse | Get-FTPItem -localpath $local_path -Overwrite -Verbose #- ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorExcep 
   tion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorExceptio 
   n,Get-FTPItem
```

Help me please understand the cause of the problem and fix it.
Thanks.

Additionally.

1. Adding `-RecreateFolders`:

   ```
   Get-FTPChildItem -path $ftp_path -Recurse | Get-FTPItem -localpath $local_path -Overwrite -Verbose -RecreateFolders
   ```

   results in the the same error

   > Get-FTPItem : Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote  server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access)." At C:\PS_Scrips\PSFTP_1.ps1:13 char:45 + ...  -Recurse | Get-FTPItem -localpath $local_path -Overwrite -Verbose -R ... +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorExcep     tion     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorExceptio     n,Get-FTPItem`
2. Executing just `Get-FTPChildItem -path $ftp_path -Recurse` returned https://pastebin.com/t9F5Th59

3. 2023/04/07 It was broken, but I can't realise why.

```
Get-FTPChildItem -path $ftp_path -Recurse |
    Where-Object { $_.Dir -ne "DIR" } |
    Get-FTPItem -localpath $local_path -Overwrite -Verbose  -RecreateFolders
```

and again get the same error:

```
Get-FTPChildItem : Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote serve
r returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access)."
At line:14 char:1
+ Get-FTPChildItem -path $ftp_path -Recurse |
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Get-FTPCh 
   ildItem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to filter-out the directory entries:

```
Get-FTPChildItem -path $ftp_path -Recurse |
    Where-Object { $_.Dir -ne "DIR" } |
    Get-FTPItem -localpath $local_path -Overwrite -Verbose -RecreateFolders
```